# How to Redirect to a Url from Jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i am Trying to Redirect a Url from a jsp using for Action.

Code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="viewBean" type="com.app" scope="request" />
<form id="RedirectForm" name="RedirectForm" action="<%=viewBean.getFormActionURI()%>"
    method="post">
```

However I am Getting Target Url as `"Existing Url+ /viewBean.getFormActionURI()"`.

How to remove `"Existing Url" part from the new url?

Answer (score 0):

Put a "/" in the action, so that it would refer the URL from the web-app root context.

In your case, it would be change in the form action as follows:

action="/<%=viewBean.getFormActionURI()%>"

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your contextroot + your servlet name...
contextRoot usually is the name of your project.

action=/nameProject/<%=viewBean.getFormActionURI()%>

I hope this helps you